# How can I solve overflow happen between two sections when using ScrollMagic and GSAP to animate them?

Tags: javascript, layout, frontend, gsap, scrollmagic

[image]

This is the first scene on intro video happen and it take 9200 time and after end it on the same
section I need to make other scene which take 100% but when second scene animation
the other section get out with overflow and then disapear and I give two secions overflow hidden and nothing happen

```
//scenes
let introVideoScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  duration: "9200",
  triggerElement: introPage,
  triggerHook: 0
})
  .setPin(introPage)
  .setTween()
  .addTo(controller);
```

and this animation happen on two sections which fade out one and the other come on it

```
let pageScene;
sections.forEach((slide, index, slides) => {
  const pageTl = gsap.timeline();
  let nextSlide = slides.length - 1 === index ? "end" : slides[index + 1];
  pageTl.fromTo(nextSlide, 4, { y: "0%" }, { y: "50%" });
  pageTl.fromTo(slide, 4, { opacity: 1, scale: 1 }, { opacity: 0, scale: 0.4 });
  pageTl.fromTo(nextSlide, 4, { y: "50%" }, { y: "0%" }, "-=4.5");
  pageTl.fromTo(burger, 6, { y: "-1000%" }, { y: "0%" });
  pageTl.fromTo(logo, 6, { y: "-1000%" }, { y: "0%" }, "-=2");

  //Create new scene
  if (slide.id === "introPage") {
    pageScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: slide,
      duration: "100%",
      triggerHook: 0,
      offset: 9200
    })





      .setPin(introPage, { pushFollowers: false })
      .setTween(pageTl)
      .addTo(controller2);

  }
  else {
    pageScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: slide,
      duration: "100%",
      triggerHook: 0
    })



      .setPin(slide, { pushFollowers: false })
      .setTween(pageTl)
      .addTo(controller2);

  }




});
```

Comment: We at GreenSock don't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead we highly recommend the official GSAP scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.

Comment: okay but u dont know any solution for this now ?